# Error "fopen(compress.zlib://https://googleapis.com/calendar/v3/...): failed to open stream" when deleting an event from PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm updating my PHP application that uses Google Calendar Service from API v2 (which uses Zend) to API v3.

I've written the code to delete the event (note that inserting an event works, as does viewing the events) but I have a problem when deleting the event: the events is deleted correctly, but afterwards I receive the following error message:

> `HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(compress.zlib://https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxxxxxxxxxxxx%40group.calendar.google.com/events/yyyyyyyyyyyy): failed to open stream: operation failed'`

The code that I use to authenticate is the following:

```
$client_id = $dati_accesso[0];
$service_account_name = $dati_accesso[1];
$key_file_location = $dati_accesso[2];
$calendar = $dati_accesso[3];

// Crea un HTTP client autenticato


if (!strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location))
    echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxx");

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name, 
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'), 
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

// Crea un istanza del servizio Calendar

$calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$gdata['service'] = $calendarService;
$calendarList = $calendarService->calendarList->listCalendarList();

//imposta il caledario specificato 
foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
//se l'id del calendario corrente è uguale a quello impostato legge il nome
    if ($calendarListEntry->getId() == $calendar){
        $gdata['id'] = $calendarListEntry->getId();
        $gdata['name'] = $calendarListEntry->getSummary();}
}

$calendarService->events->delete($gdata['id'], $idevent);
```

Where is the error?

Comment: I have disabled gzip and now work, if somebody write a solution with gzip enabled it's well accpted